# Convert Method to Linq Expression for query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, expression-trees

In our application we want to have standard methods for various conditions in our database. For instance, we have different types of transactions, and we want to create standard methods for retrieving them within other queries. However, this gives us the error:

> Method '' has no supported translation to SQL

The method might look like this:

```
public static bool IsDividend(this TransactionLog tl)
{
    return tl.SourceTypeID == (int)JobType.Dividend || tl.SourceTypeID == (int)JobType.DividendAcct;
}
```

To be used as such:

```
var dividends = ctx.TransactionLogs.Where(x => x.IsDividend());
```

Of course, if I copy the logic from `IsDividend()` into the `Where` clause, this works fine, but I end up duplicating this logic many places and is hard to track down if that logic changes.

I think if I would convert this to an expression like this it would work, but this is not as preferable a setup as being able to use methods:

```
public Expression<Func<TransactionLog, bool>> IsDividend = tl => tl.SourceTypeID == (int)JobType.Dividend || tl.SourceTypeID == (int)JobType.DividendAcct;

var dividends = ctx.TransactionLogs.Where(IsDividend);
```

Is there a way to force Linq to evaluate the method as an expression? Or to "transform" the method call into an expression within a linq query? Something like this:

```
var dividends = ctx.TransactionLogs.Where(tl => ToExpression(tl.IsDividend));
```

We are using Linq-to-SQL in our application.

Comment: Expressions can be easily transformed to method (that is what they are designed for) but the opposite operation is a task equivalent to decompilation.

Answer (score 1):

Well having static property containing the expressions seems fine to me.

The only way to make it work with Methods would be to create a method which returns this expression, and then call it inside where:

```
public class TransactionLog 
{
    Expression<Func<TransactionLog, bool>> IsDividend() {
        Expression<Func<TransactionLog, bool>> expression = tl => tl.SourceTypeID == (int)JobType.Dividend || tl.SourceTypeID == (int)JobType.DividendAcct;
        return expression;
    }
}

public class TransactionLogExtension
{
    Expression<Func<TransactionLog, bool>> IsDividend(this TransactionLog log) {
        Expression<Func<TransactionLog, bool>> expression = tl => tl.SourceTypeID == (int)JobType.Dividend || tl.SourceTypeID == (int)JobType.DividendAcct;
        return expression;
    }
}
```

and use it via

```
var dividends = ctx.TransactionLogs.Where(TransactionLog.IsDividend());
```

or as extension method

```
var dividends = ctx.TransactionLogs.Where(x.IsDividend());
```

But none of it is will work with `var dividends = ctx.TransactionLogs.Where(x => x.IsDividend());` because `x => x.IsDividend();` itself is an expression tree and your database provider can't translate "IsDividend" into an SQL statement.

But the other two options will at least allow you to pass in parameters (which doesn't work if you store the Expressions as instance or static properties).

Answer (score 0):

I think that LINQ to SQL doesn't fully supports even common and build-in functions. (At least EF does not do it). And moreover - when it deals with user defined methods. I predict that your variant with expression will fall as well as the variant with method call unless you call it after enumeration (ToList or similar method). I suggest to keep the balance between 1) stored procedures at server, 2) common conditions hardcoded in `Where` clauses in C#, 3) expression trees generation in C#. All these points are relatively complex, for sure (and to my mind there is no easy and general solution).

Answer (score 0):

Try using Extension Methods, like so:

```
public static class TransactionLogExtensions {
    public static IQueryable<TransactionLog> OnlyDividends(this IQueryable<TransactionLog> tl)
    {
        return tl.Where(t=>t.SourceTypeID == (int)JobType.Dividend || t.SourceTypeID == (int)JobType.DividendAcct);
    }
}
```

Call it like so:

```
var dividends=db.TransactionLogs.OnlyDividends();
```

or

```
var dividends=db.TransactionLogs.OnlyDividends().OrderBy(...);
```

Comment: Another alternative is to create extension methods that create a virtual view of your data.  Use whatever your `ctx` object, and create an extension method on it that returns only dividends... `public static class ctxobjectypeExtension { public static IQueryable<TransactionLog> Dividends(this ctxobjecttype ctx) { return ctx.TransactionLogs.Where(tl=>tl.SourceTypeID == (int)JobType.Dividend || tl.SourceTypeID == (int)JobType.DividendAcct)); }}`  called like `var dividends=ctx.Dividends();`

Answer (score -1):

For this scenario you can use Func. Linq works very good with those.
Here is the simple example of using Func in Linq query. Feel free to modify and use.

```
Func<int,bool> isDivident = x => 3==x;
int[] values = { 3, 7, 10 };
var result = values.Select (isDivident );
```

Comment: This will not be able to translate the query into SQL, as the question is asking about.

Comment: You right, directly against SQL it will not, but when you do your select ToList() it works perfectly, and has same performance impact as another possible solutions.

Comment: No, it doesn't work perfectly.  It doesn't execute the query in the database *at all*.  It has *dramatically* worse performance as it means pulling down the entire contents of the database into memory only to act on it in memory, and the result of that is that it can quite plausibly not work at all (there may not be enough memory, it could be too much data to pull from the database, it could easily cause the operation to time out, etc.).